# Unable to load the requested language file: language/en/form_validation_lang.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2.1.4

In that I am using `form_validation` library for form validation.

When I try to run that function I get following error

> Unable to load the requested language file: language/en/form_validation_lang.php

I have scanned all of the files. I am not using or calling this language file in any file still and I am getting this error.

```
function insert(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username_field', 'username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname_field', 'firstname', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname_field', 'lastname', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_field', 'email', 'required|valid_email|callback_isEmailExist');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $this->create();

    }
}

function isEmailExist($email) {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $is_exist = $this->users->isEmailExist($email);

    if ($is_exist) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(
            'isEmailExist', 'Email address is already exist.'
        );    
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Be sure that /application/language/en/form_validation_lang.php exists.
And also check that $config['language'] is properly set.

Comment: How you are loading the form_validation library?

Comment: $this->load->library('form_validation'); I am loading library by calling it like this.

Comment: Have you tried `$this->lang->load('form_validation', 'english')` If you are trying to call the one from the system folder no need to. Please show your controller where you are having issue.

Comment: but I don't want to call lang of form_validation I don't need that

Comment: Have a look in the system folder language and see if it there

Comment: Are you using the `set_message` method from `form_validation`?

Comment: yes I am using set_message method @thiagobraga

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your error. Can you paste some lines of your code  in your question where you load and use `form_validation`?

Comment: Must be missing the system/language/en/form_validation_lang.php **Also Have you by mistake loaded the form_validation language in autoload.php**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CI `form_validation` library uses language file for display error message.You are using `required` `valid_email` those error message is written inside `form_validation_lang.php`.

`form_validation` library loads the language file(`form_validation_lang.php`) itself whether you load or not.You can open the library file and look at the run function you will see a line `$this->CI->lang->load('form_validation');`

This file located either inside your `system/language/your_language/` or `application/language/your_language/`.

That error message says you missed the file inside any of the folder.If you download the original CI files it should be inside `system/language/english/` folder.If you don't see the file [download](http://www.codeigniter.com/download) CI and restore the file there.

Answer (score 8):

there are two locations whith language files
 1. in the `system/language` folder
 2. in the `application/language` folder

For formvalidation CI uses the `system/language` folder

in your config.php (in the `application/config`) you specify wich language folder you want to use.

So, open your config file and look for

```
$config['language'] = 'en';
```

look into your `system/language` folder and look if there is a folder named "en" and if there is a `form_validation_lang.php` file in it.

if not, I think there is a folder named `english`.
then the solutions would be to change the `'en'` in your config to `english`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `application/config/config.php` you should have `$config['language']  = 'en';`.
Change it to `$config['language'] = 'english';`.