# An Error Was Encountered, Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/sms_lang.php

Tags: php

localhost system works well but on system upload to server, i try to log in with my username and password, i get this error:

> Unable to load the requested language file:
>   language/english/sms_lang.php

The file keeps deleting automatically on and on.

I tried to rename "English" to "en" in `config.php` and folder fro, "english" to "en" in application/language/english

expected to login smoothly like on my local host

Comment: Do you use Codeigniter? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896938/unable-to-load-the-requested-language-file-language-en-form-validation-lang-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896938/unable-to-load-the-requested-language-file-language-en-form-validation-lang-php)

Comment: Check permissions, check casing (linux is case sensitive, windows is not)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: well, am not good at programming, how ever, in my files here, i see CodeIgniter php file in upload/system/core/codeigniter.php

Comment: yes am using codeigniter, anyone to help me, or give me a solution on this?