# How to escape Codeigniter Language feature?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to perform an `Ajax` post operation via Detail controller with `Ajax`. But I am encountering this error:

> Unable to load the requested language file:
> language/positive-flag/general_lang.php

Ajax:

```
$('#positive').on('click', function() {      
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/positive-flag',
    data: dataJson,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
    }
    });
});
```

Route File:

```
$route['positive-flag']['post']     = 'detail/positiveFlag';
$route['negative-flag']['post']     = 'detail/negativeFlag';
$route['unknown-flag']['post']      = 'detail/unknownFlag';
```

I do not want the language feature to be attached to these functions.
I hope I could explain what I mean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896938/unable-to-load-the-requested-language-file-language-en-form-validation-lang-php/29948588 Maybe this is what you looking for

Comment: No it is not...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed.
solution is use fetch_method() function.